# Bootstrap 3.3.2 Center modal on all viewport sizes with or without vertical scrollbar

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am getting the impression that the Bootstrap 3.3.2 modal still needs a lot of work. Not only is the nasty bug  [Open modal is shifting body content to the left #9855](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9855) **still** not resolved, see here  [Modify scrollbar check, stop static nav shift #13103](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/13103)  (comments at the bottom), no, even the default modal on the live BS site is **not** centred and I assume bug #9855 (linked above) is also causing this [Modal hides the vertical browser scrollbar #1081](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/issues/1081) .

If you check the BS site as a code example [Bootstrap modal optional sizes](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-sizes), click either the large or small modal demo at a decent viewport width the modal "seems" centred. Though it is **not**.

When resizing the browser so that the modal nearly fills the viewport width one can clearly observe that the modal is leaning to the left hand side of the browser, I assume due to Bootstrap messing up the scrollbar width calculations or generally messing round with the scrollbar and its width.

Now there is two options, either use a modal plugin that does not come from BS (there is plenty of modal plugins that perfectly center horizontally and vertically in the viewport as well as being responsive), or, somehow start putting some work into the BS modal and get those issues fixed.

I am still trying to go with the BS default modal and am trying to center it, in this case horizontally, on all viewport sizes, taking into consideration the vertical scrollbar being shown or not, depending on the height of the modal.

As can be seen in this beautiful example [Centering Percentage Width/Height Elements](http://css-tricks.com/centering-percentage-widthheight-elements/) it is possible to center elements, that even have a percentage value as width and height in the viewport.

To come to my question, would the technique showcased by Chris Coyier, here you have an example code, [Codepen: Percentage sized and still centered](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/BvdgL) work with BS 3.3.2?

```
  div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

I am sure there is plenty of devs out there that have had this exact same issue, simply centering the modal on all viewport sizes either with or without vertical scrollbar. Chris's example works very well with the vertical scrollbar. So would wrapping the .modal-dialog in a div with  Chris's centering technique finally get rid of this and subsequent bugs?

How do you center the BS 3.3.2 modal on all viewport sizes with or without a vertical scrollbar being shown, depending on the modal's height?

To be honest I am really not amused about the BS modal, at first glance it all seems to look and work very smooth but if you actually start development with it there is so many issues that come up and are so old, it kind of frustrates me, so please do forgive me for the possibly harsh tone here. I am just really wanting to use BS instead of having to spend time on how to fix issues that other plugins seem to master perfectly with a few lines of code.

Any help, or technique (including code) that really centers the modal horizontally in the viewport is really very much appreciated, be this with CSS or jQuery. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Basically the Web stack sucks so badly that creating a proper modal is super-frickin-hard, especially when trying to be compatible with IE8 like Bootstrap does.

Comment: @cvrebert Sorry for the late reply, did not get notified about the comments. Being compatible with IE8 is tough, point taken, though having the entire body jump in latest versions of Chrome and Firefox, even on the getbootstrap.com site is something that can be fixed with the few lines of code. Though I am far from a pro so please don't mind my simple approach of simply applying equal padding to both sides of the modal, perhaps that logic also has flaws that I have not discovered yet. What do you think about the approach below? Your opinion on this would mean lots to me, u being pro. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

My approach that seems to work on **all** viewport sizes **regardless** of a **vertical** scrollbar being present or **not** is to measure the padding that BS 3.3.2 applies to the `body.modal-open` class (where do those 17px come from?) once the modal is open and apply this padding on both sides of the modal.

I wrapped this in a function once the `shown.bs.modal` event has fired to make sure the modal has finished loading. For remote content you might have to apply `loaded.bs.modal` instead.

If `body.modal-open` does not have a right padding the padding is also removed from the left. Tested in latest version of Chrome and Firefox.

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {


    // meassure the padding-right given by BS and apply it as padding-left to the modal
    // like this equal padding on either side of the modal is given regardless of media query
    var modalPaddingRight = $('#myModal').css('padding-right');
    console.log ('modalPaddingRight = ' + modalPaddingRight);


    // apply the padding value from the right to the left
    $('#myModal').css('padding-left', modalPaddingRight);
    console.log ( 
            'modalPaddingLeft = ' + $('#myModal').css('padding-left') +
            ' modalPaddingRight = ' + $('#myModal').css('padding-right')
            );


    // apply equal padding on window resize
    var modalPaddingLeft = function () {

        var modalPaddingRight = $('#myModal').css('padding-right');
        console.log ('modalPaddingRight = ' + modalPaddingRight);

        $('#myModal').css('padding-left', modalPaddingRight);
        console.log ( 
            'modalPaddingLeft = ' + $('#myModal').css('padding-left') +
            'modalPaddingRight = ' + $('#myModal').css('padding-right')
            );
    };

    $(window).resize(modalPaddingLeft);
});
```

I am no jQuery hero, so **PLEASE** if there is a more elegant way to code this or another faster, better, nicer approach to this that works **regardless** of a **vertical** scrollbar being present or **not**, do let me know.

Thank you :)

Comment: "where do those 17px come from?": https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/ad379ffb4a0fde7416ae076e68141300fc583018/js/modal.js#L264

Answer (score 0):

Using css we can place Bootstrap modal at vertical center.

```
    .modal {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0!important;
    }

    .modal:before {
        content: '';
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin: -2px;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .modal-dialog {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

[Bootstrap modal responsive vertical centering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674110/bootstrap-modal-responsive-vertical-centering/37171464#37171464)